# Determine the set of points at which the function is continuous for the following piecewise function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2y^3/(2x^2 + y^2)  & \text{if $(x,y)$ ≠ (0,0)} \\
1 & \text{if $(x,y)$ = (0,0)}
\end{cases}

How can I use the squeeze theorem to explain that f is continuous for the set $(x,y)$ ≠ (0,0)

I understand that

f(x) =$\frac{x^2y^3}{(2x^2 +y^2)}$

is less than

f(x) =$y^3$

but I'm  unsure of another equation I could use to apply the squeeze theorem

Comment: The first function isn't non-positive and there are plenty of points where it's not defined (and hence not continuous).

Comment: not helpful, but thx anyway